# Openlayers + Superfish safari conflict

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, openlayers, superfish

Using Drupal 7, Openlayers, and Superfish causes a bizzarre error. On menu items with sub nav items, the top menu item disappears until you hover over it. Once hovering, it displays properly with the subnav. This only occurs on pages which the openlayers js is called.

Upon inspecting, there are no zindex issues, no js errors that appear and it seems like the superfish js works properly since the navigation slides in just fine.

On this page, the navigation doesn't work until you hover: http://dev2.esavalanche.org/

On this page, the navigation works fine: http://dev2.esavalanche.org/node/18

I have noticed that the items appear for a second before disappearing.

This problem is only in Safari as far as I can tell. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar problem with a solution here: http://drupal.org/node/1748514 apparently openlayers also uses translate3d

adding

```
#superfish-1 ul,
#superfish-1  li {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 1px);
}
```

in the css fixed the disappearing menu items.